# make AJAX\jQuery\JavaScript load pictures?

Tags: jquery

I want to load picture from web server without refreshing the page.
I have simple page:

```
<body><h1>Test</h1>
      <div id="mydiv">
         <img src="animals.jpg"/>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the point is that animals.jpg content changes (i.e now animals.jpg can be picture of wolf but after minute it will be changed to a cat) however the name(animal.jpg) stays ( server overwrites the image content *only* ) 
so what i want is when i click on the picture it will re-load it from the server.

what i did so far (actually it's made of pieces of examples i found :) ):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydiv').click(function(){
        //$('#mydiv').load("animals.jpg") // loads text instead of image
        //$("#mydiv").append("<img src='animals.jpg'/>"); // appends old picture
        //$("#mydiv").html("<img src='animals.jpg'/>") // not responds at all
    }); 
})
```

not working, see the comments.

Though I can load html's:
**loadme.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#mydiv').click(function(){
     $('#mydiv').load("h1.html")
   }); 
 })


</script>

</head>

<body><h1>Test</h1>
<div id="mydiv">
load me!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**h1.html**:

## Text

now when i change h1.html 'text' on something else and i click on 'load me!' in load.html it will updated content always.
That's what i want to achieve with images :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the image's `src` attribute to get it to reload. As the `src` is supposed to stay the same, append a random string to the end of it. This'll make the browser think it's a new image.

```
$('#mydif>img').attr('src', 'animals.jpg?random=' + Math.random());
```

Comment: Thanks, it's finally working!.
    $('img').attr('src', 'animals.jpg?random=' + Math.random());
( with a little modification )

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way, for me:

```
<img id="myimg" src="animal.jpg"/>
```

Just set the src attribute with Javascript:

```
function f()
{
   var img = document.getElementById("myimg");
   img.src = "your_new_pic.jpg";
}
```

Of course, if you need animations or other cool stuff, it's better to use JQUERY.

Comment: Don't think you understood the question. He's looking for a way to get JavaScript to **reload** an image (cachebusting).